# How to convert 13 digit string to date of format d-m-Y in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, date, unix-timestamp

I am having problems converting 13 digit string to date which should have following format m-d-Y.
This is my 13 digit date string - **1415855073164**

I have tried this.

```
$date123 = $rawDataPopup[$i]['datetime'];   //1415855073164
$convertFromDate=($date123 )/1000; // dividing by 1000 which gives me 10 digit string.
```

What to do next to get m-d-Y date format.

Comment: `"13 digit date string"` - FYI this is known as an [epoch timestamp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time). The value you have is in milliseconds.

Comment: but epoch time will be having 10 digit rite?

Comment: correct, @minspace-six - Usually epoch is represented in seconds (10 digits), but in this case you are dealing with milliseconds which have an extra 3 digit precision.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to pass the unix epoch timestamp (seconds since 1/1/1970) to the PHP [`date( $format, $timestamp )`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function.

```
$tsSeconds = $rawDataPopup[$i]['datetime'] / 1000;
date( 'Y-m-d', $tsSeconds );
```

Comment: @minspacesix PHP is not expecting a milliseconds value. You need to convert the timestamp into seconds first. The date function is expecting the same value returned by the [`time()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) function which is in seconds.

Comment: Its giving me 46836-08-29,  for the string 1415855073164. How do i filter it again?

Comment: You are using the timestamp in milliseconds, you need to divide by 1000 to pass seconds to the date() function.

Comment: Thanks Lix and doublesharp. Its working for me. Cheers